# kubernetes understanding configmap from volume

Tags: go, kubernetes, configmap

I am playing around with kubernetes config map and wanted to understand how the volume mounts work

I have a json config file called `client_config.json` that is

```
{
  "name": "place",
  "animal": "thing",
  "age": 10
}
```

I created a config map using the command

```
kubectl create configmap client-config --from-file=client_config.json
```

I then mount it to a volume onto my deployment as

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: go-web-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: go-web-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: go-web-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: application
          image: my/repo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: /client-config
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: client-config
```

In my go application I am able to read the config using

```
func config(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filepath.Clean("./client_config.json"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, fmt.Sprintf("error reading config: %s", err))
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, fmt.Sprintf("config value is : %s", string(b)))
    }

}
```

My question is that configmap was mounted to a mount path as

```
mountPath: /client-config
```

But I am reading it from the code as

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filepath.Clean("./client_config.json"))
```

What is the use of the mount path `/client-config` when I do not need to even reference it when I am reading the configmap as a file ?

Comment: k8s secrets, configmaps, pvc's etc. all have to be mounted somewhere for the containers to access them. Your app's working directory is most likely already using `/client-config`. If you change the path in your deployment YAML, it should fail.

Comment: The other thing I might check is whether the configuration file is unintentionally being included in the image.

Comment: @DavidMaze you are right I was including the file in the image. After I removed it I had to correct the code to include the mount path. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze)'s comment I was able to resolve the issue.

Issue was I was including the `client_config.json` file along with the image, because of which my code was able to reference it via the path `./client_config.json`

After I rebuilt the image without `client_config.json` in it I got the error

```
error reading config: open client_config.json: no such file or directory
```

I then corrected my code to use the mount path and I am now able to read the configmap as a file from the volume

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filepath.Clean("/client-config/client_config.json"))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, fmt.Sprintf("error reading config: %s", err))
} else {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, fmt.Sprintf("config value is : %s", string(b)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`./client_config.json` is a relative file path. Most probably, your app's current working directory is `/client-config`. Your actual file is located at `/client-config/client_config.json`.